# How to disable a collections of dates for Telerik DateTimePicker?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, datetimepicker

For a telerik DateTimePicker, I need you to disable a collection of certain dates, so user cannot select them? Is there any client/server side events that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wire the DayRender server and client events of the calendar inside the picker - I found a [demo project](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/calendar/disabling-calendar-days.aspx) on the telerik site about that.

Comment: Upon telrik documentation and APIs, DayRender event supported only by Calendar control, and not supported by DateTimePicker control?